# Spark-GraphX: create anRDD from an ArrayBuffer of String

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have an ArrayBuffer of Strings that contains the labels of all the vertices of the graph I want to create. I need to create a RDD object `[(VertexId, String)]` which are going to be the nodes for my future graph, where VertexId for each node = index of the node's label in the ArrayBuffer.
I found only information about creating an RDD using `SparkContext.textFile(String fname)`, but nothing on how to create RDD from datastructures.

Is there a way to do this or do I always have to create the RDD from a file?

Comment: Since you found " nothing on how to create RDD from datastructures" I assume you are not aware of the scaladocs for Spark. These are pretty essential for using Spark and scala - they can be found here. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the parallelize method:

```scala
val data = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
val distData = sc.parallelize(data)
```

Parallelized collections are created by calling SparkContext’s parallelize method on an existing collection in your driver program (a Scala Seq). The elements of the collection are copied to form a distributed dataset that can be operated on in parallel.

So considering your ArrayBuffer[(VertexId,String)], you'll need to transform that into a Seq before and then passing it as an argument to sc.parallelize

According the ArrayBuffer [scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer) you can apply the method toSeq on your arraybuffer directly.

```
val distData = sc.parallelize(data.toSeq) // data your arraybuffer.
```

If your arraybuffer is like described in the question of type `ArrayBuffer[(VertedId,String)]` , `distData` will be an `RDD[(VertedId,String)]`